# Is it possible to track Metrics within a sink such as FileIO?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Playing around with `org.apache.beam.sdk.metrics` was wondering the following... **Can you track metrics from** an "obscure" (and by obscure I mean that the **code of that stage is not yours**) to catch failures, delays and such like, for example, within the `CassandraIO` connector when inserts fail?

If so, how can I access that information?

So far I've been tracking metrics within my very own stages doing `Metrics.counter("new_counter", "new_metric").inc(n)` and similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metrics need to be added manually to each connector, much like you already do with your own metrics (i.e. `Metrics.counter(.....).inc(..)`).

If the connector has metrics of its own, it will publish them. Unfortunately, it seems like that's not the case for `CassandraIO`. : (

If you are interested, I would invite you to submit a pull request to the Apache Beam repository to add metrics that you find interesting for CassandraIO or any other connector that you like.